# Transpose column to row using awk

Tags: awk

In my data file, there is a certain column I am interested. So I used awk to print out only that column (awk '{print $4}') and put a condition to eliminate using "if". However, I could not figure out how to transpose every nth line on that column to new row.

input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

desired output:

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

I have checked out the other solutions and tried but none of them gave me what I want. I will appreciate if anyone could help me with that.

Comment: I just checked, no it is not.

Comment: your input is always with `x^2` lines?  what if you have a `15` lines file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can also use `pr` here

```
$ seq 9 | pr -3ts' '
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
$ seq 9 | pr -5ts' '
1 3 5 7 9
2 4 6 8
```

where the number indicates how many columns you need and the `s` option allows to specify the delimiter between columns

Comment: just a way to create input data.. `seq` is useful to create sequence of numbers, it allows to specify start, end and step values as needed

Comment: Oh, I see. How can do if I want to check each number on the column and if a number is less than the number which comes next, put space and keep on going till the end of the file

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
$ seq 9 | 
awk ' {
    i=((i=NR%3)?i:3)                # index to hash a
    a[i]=a[i] (a[i]==""?"":" ") $1  # space separate items to a[i]
} 
END {
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)               # from 1 to 3 (yes, hardcoded)
        print a[i]                  # output
}'
```

Output:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: Thank you! I also tried your way and It worked!  I wish I could choose more than one answer!

Answer (score 2):

The `columns` program from the autogen package can do this, e.g.:

```
seq 9 | columns --by-column -w1 -c3
```

Output:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: I haven't tried your way but Thank you for your help!